# Given a thread's id or handle, how can I determine the thread's state?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, asynchronous

This function below pretends to extend the [`Thread.Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function (or Win32 [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`SleepEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx)) which only affects to the calling thread.

In my `suspendFunc` lambda I would like to ensure whether the thread is really suspended, before calling `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)`.

I've been searching **[related Win32 thread functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** to retrieve the thread's state from a thread handle or thread id but I didn't found anything similar, neither I can't find an structure or enumeration that defines the thread states (only the **[managed one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**) so I didn't found any hint to start doing it.

How I could do this?.

---

(Note: P/Invokes are not supplied in the shared code, I think they are not necessary to understand and only will increase the code size.)

C#:

```
public static void SleepThread(int threadId, TimeSpan timespan)
{
    IntPtr hThread = default(IntPtr);
    int win32Err = 0;

    // Returns the previous suspend count for the thread.
    Func<int> suspendFunc = () =>
    {
        int suspendCount = 0;
        Debug.WriteLine("Sleeping...");
        Thread.Sleep(timespan);
        Debug.WriteLine("Resuming thread...");
        suspendCount = ResumeThread(hThread);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
        return suspendCount;
    };

    hThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccessRights.SuspendResume | ThreadAccessRights.Terminate, true, threadId);
    win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    if ((hThread == IntPtr.Zero)) {
        throw new Win32Exception(win32Err);

    } else {
        Debug.WriteLine("Pausing thread...");
        Task<int> suspendTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(suspendFunc);
        SuspendThread64(hThread);

    }

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//=======================================================
```

VB.NET:

```vb
Public Shared Sub SleepThread(ByVal threadId As Integer, ByVal timespan As TimeSpan)

    Dim hThread As IntPtr
    Dim win32Err As Integer

    Dim suspendFunc As Func(Of Integer) =
        Function() As Integer ' Returns the previous suspend count for the thread.
            Dim suspendCount As Integer
            Debug.WriteLine("Sleeping...")
            Thread.Sleep(timespan)
            Debug.WriteLine("Resuming thread...")
            suspendCount = ResumeThread(hThread)
            CloseHandle(hThread)
            Return suspendCount
        End Function

    hThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccessRights.SuspendResume Or ThreadAccessRights.Terminate, True, threadId)
    win32Err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

    If (hThread = IntPtr.Zero) Then
        Throw New Win32Exception(win32Err)

    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("Pausing thread...")
        Dim suspendTask As Task(Of Integer) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Integer)(suspendFunc)
        SuspendThread64(hThread)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the .NET implementation of threads tracks this information itself. The larger question is why are you re-implementing Thread.Sleep. For starters, the very use of this function is a sign of a poorly designed program. And certainly not something that makes sense for *another* thread, one that you do not own. If you want to suspend such a thread, call the `SuspendThread` function. But really, don't, because suspended a thread is a bad idea unless you are writing a debugger. Otherwise, deadlock city.

Comment: Suspending a non-owned thread doesn't need to mean a poorly designed program, it is very helpful, best and only approach in a lot of scenarios, one simple example: If you are using a 3rd party command-line tool that performs a long task (let's say FFMPEG, a video converter tool) and that you wrapped their functionalities in a .NET based GUI, and then you want to add Pause/Resume features in your GUI, SuspendThread/ResumeThread is required, if not, how you will interop with the external app's thread to do such thing?. You see, it makes sense. Thanks for comment!

Comment: It sounds good, but it is an epic failure waiting to happen. What if that long task is multi-threaded? You can't just suspend one thread. And yeah, I guess you could suspend *all* of the FFMPEG threads, but then you're back to using SuspendThread. No need to write all of this code, and no need for this question.

Comment: Why does this question have so many downvotes? Even if the intention of the QO is not a good coding practice, the question itself is well-asked and formatted.

Comment: @AlexB.: Formatting doesn't turn an impractical programming question into a good question. The OP (and potentially future visitors) does not appear to understand the implications of suspending a thread. This is a broad subject, and needs to be laid out before even beginning to address the question asked. As such, the question is **way** too broad (and hardly ever practical).

Comment: @IInspectable Don't mix my intentions (what you consider bad) with the question itself, the question says:  "**Given a thread's id or handle, how can I determine the thread's state?**", is that an impractical programming question that deserves a couple of downvotes?, of course NOT, it would be very usefull information for much people how to determine the state of a external thread, I think it is very interesting. How you can say the question is too broad?, the question is mroe than clear.

Comment: Your question may be clear. And yet, it is complete bogus (*"In my `suspendFunc` lambda I would like to ensure whether the thread is really suspended, before calling `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)`."*). In other words: You want to query a property (that's useless) to determine whether or not to run hypothetical code (which you cannot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I can get.

```vb
Function GetThreadState(ProcId As Integer, ThreadId As Integer) As Threading.ThreadState
    For Each Thr As Threading.Thread In Process.GetProcessById(ProcId).Threads
        If Thr.ManagedThreadId = ThreadId Then Return Thr.ThreadState
    Next
    Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Thread not found.")
End Function
```